# How to know which line or selector (XPath or byCss) caused the error/exception

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

The stack trace provided by Protractor in case of an error sometimes doesn't reveal the **selector** that caused the error. For example a message reads

```
ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
```

What `element`? How to know what was the line that caused the error in the first place?

I'm using it with `buildbot` so there is no way to use the debug feature.

Comment: You should paste the entire output.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question!

Currently, the Protractor API (even on 2.1.0) only displays the bland error message you've mentioned. Here is one possible method of alleviating the debugging pain:

- Don't use <*element*>.click() arbitrarily, but **route it** through a helper function, e.g.

  `function clickElemByCSS(sel)  { return clickElem(element(By.css(sel), sel); }`
  `function clickElem(elem, sel) { return elem.click().then(..); }`
  [...] abr., **see below** for more ideas on error handling

  *NOTE: The parameters' and functions' names were edited for brevity*.

  Then `require` your helper file in your spec file and use the `clickElementByCSS` (also a good idea to host other `By`s, e.g. by ID, XPath and so on). This usage of a forwarding/routing function makes for a bit better debugging:
- Use an **error handler** (in Angular/ES6 promise lingo: *a `catch()`* block):

  ```
  function clickElement(element, selector) {
    return element.click().then(null, function errorHandler(error) {
      console.error("Element not found" +
                    "(selector: ') + selector + '): " + 
                    parseStackTrace(error.stack));
  }
  ```

  The generated `Error` ('exception') object has a `stack` property which can be altered and thus is of great use in this case.

  The `parseStackTrace` can be defined by '`grep`-ing' over the humongous stack trace and searching for the name of your helper method, e.g. the line with `at clickElement`.

  Then you can get a number of previous lines (say, 5 lines for context) and just have them outputted instead of the whole stack trace, which sadly includes much internal Selenium-Protractor interaction noise. This saves you the effort of scrolling through 100+ lines *per exception* to find the piece of code you're interested in (i.e. the one which caused the exception).

  For instance, `parseStackTrace` could use something like

  `stack.match(/at clickElement(.*[\n]){1,5}/i)` (not foolproof but still).

  Obviously, one can improve and pass the [`displayName`](https://medium.com/@cramforce/on-the-awesomeness-of-fn-displayname-9511933a714a) of the function and build the `RegEx` dynamically.

Here's to hoping that the stack trace can be truncated automagically in further Protractor versions.

As an interesting cross-pollination of this issue, a project called `cucumber-js` also has its share of complains about `webdriver`'s long stack traces. One can adapt the [monkeypatching presented in this comment](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/157#issuecomment-43309248) to his/her needs just fine.